# What happens if a player makes an illegal move and nobody notices?

Tags: rules, illegal-move

What happens if a player makes an illegal move (i.e. a realistic case could be, he castles after he already moved the King), but none of the player notices, and the game goes on and on for a lot of moves? Is the final result to be taken as valid? On another note, what happens if a player, after some moves, realizes that, say, move 10 was illegal, and could not be made?

Comment: Related, although asked about blitz & bullet - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/181/i-made-an-illegal-move-what-happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FIDE laws of chess state:

> If during a game it is found that an illegal move, including failing
>   to meet the requirements of the promotion of a pawn or capturing the
>   opponent’s king, has been completed, the position immediately before
>   the irregularity shall be reinstated. If the position immediately
>   before the irregularity cannot be determined the game shall continue
>   from the last identifiable position prior to the irregularity. The
>   clocks shall be adjusted according to Article 6.13. The Articles 4.3
>   and 4.6 apply to the move replacing the illegal move. The game shall
>   then continue from this reinstated position.

So basically the game should be reverted to before that move, using the game record.

Edit: These are for standard play. Other time controls have different rules, and although most national federations basically just apply the FIDE rules, they can sometimes be different.

Comment: So if the game has ended, it should be repeated from that move?

Comment: No. The rule applies only to games in progress (including adjudication), except I believe if the illegal move was the final move.

It would be interesting to know if anybody has used this rule as a mulligan in case the game doesn't go their way, to be able to revert back to an earlier point.

Comment: Interesting. Once in a tournament, I was in check, but neither of us noticed. Then, my opponent noticed and we didn't know what to do, so we called a staff over. The staff said once a move is done and the next person moves then you can't go back. This was repeated by my chess coach. We both had our notation. However, once, I made an illegal move in a chess tournament and my opponent saw and called the director over and I had to redo the move. He said there is a rule where 3 illegal moves and you lose. We also weren't playing with time.